# Definition of symbol of differential operators

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

The [symbol of differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator) has a confusing definition as a "polynomial" it is
$$\sigma_P(x,\xi) := \Sigma_{|\alpha|= k} P_\alpha(x)\xi^\alpha$$
So what is $\xi^{(1,2)}? $ Is it the polynomial $\xi_1\xi_2?$

[Page 6 line 7](https://nikno.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/psido.pdf), also, what is the definition of

$$(A^t(\tilde{x}) \xi)^\alpha $$
Equivalently, for a fixed matrix $A$, what is
$$ (A \xi)^\alpha $$

Comment: The link you posted contains another link to 'muli-index' which explains the notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation

Comment: I believe you should change $|\alpha|\leq k$ to $|\alpha|=k$.

Comment: And the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @Amitai, I added my new concern, what is the defintiion in this case?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval The meaning of $\xi^{(1,2)}$ is $\xi_1\xi^2_2$, cf the link I put into my first comment. And it is a multiindex for elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\xi_1\xi_2$ would be $ \xi^{(1,1)}$

Comment: @Thomas  Thanks  alot. What does the matrix case mean? I have linked the pdf which I am reading from.

Comment: Well, $A\xi$ is a vector which you can write down with respect to a given basis - it's component are $(A\xi)_i = \sum_j a_{ij}\xi_j$. Now apply the definition.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense , thanks a lot Thomas!